# The reputation on deleted question

Tags: feature-request, reputation, accepted-answer, deleted-questions

I think the bounty/reputation should be preserved for the answers even after the question is deleted. I mean you give an answer and it is accepted and then question gets deleted because of some reason... It is not my problem.So, the reputation earned through votes up or accepted answer must not be decreased for the person answering the question. It is kind of not fair sometimes. I got an answer with 3 votes up and accepted and then later question got deleted and my reputation was drastically decreased. hmmm... its not all about reputation but just not fair. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I think the bounty/reputation should be preserved for the answers even after the question is deleted.

There are [specific conditions in which rep on deleted posts are preserved:](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)

> First, if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you
>   should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets
>   deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

---

> It is kind of not fair sometimes.

Well, nothing's fair in this world.

Comment: @EliahKagan I've corrected the link - thanks for letting me know

Comment: A mod deleted a question and I had an answer with there a score of 3, then it was 30 rep down the drain!

Comment: @EmersonHsieh Considering that you have almost 2000 reputation, that 30 rep is probably a relatively small amount in the larger scheme of things. You'll probably regain it soon anyway from your other contributions (if you haven't already).

Comment: @EliahKagan Just saying...  And I earned my rep back already

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced this is really unfair. If others cannot benefit from the post, why should the reputation be retained? Reputation is supposed to say something about certain kinds of contributions that exist in the community from a user. (It's a intended as a [rough gauge of how much we trust them](https://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation), so it should be possible to infer it, for the most part, by looking at their contributions.)

Furthermore, while I don't think it's necessarily bad to answer a question you think might get closed and deleted (or just deleted), I don't think there's any good reason to go out of our way to create rules incentivizing the creation of posts that are likely to be invisible due to their parent questions being deleted.